# How to make a working li item delete button and display the delete button whenever the new li tag is created?

Tags: javascript, html, project

HERE'S THE CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>INDEX</title>
    <style>
        .unordered li{
            float:left;
            margin: 10px;
            list-style: none;
        }
        .unordered button{
            background: lightcoral;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .unordered button:hover{
            background: rgb(231, 85, 85);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>INDEX</h1>
          <ul class="unordered">
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
         </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to make a site in which whenever I create a new li tag a delete button is displayed with the li and when I click on it, it deletes the li. And I want to display the delete button without doing the coding for each one. Please help in doing that

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code(first get all the buttons,then add `click` event listener to each button):

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
for(let i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
    buttons[i].parentNode.remove()
  })
}
```

Test code

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
for(let i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
    buttons[i].parentNode.remove()
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>INDEX</title>
    <style>
        .unordered li{
            float:left;
            margin: 10px;
            list-style: none;
        }
        .unordered button{
            background: lightcoral;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .unordered button:hover{
            background: rgb(231, 85, 85);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>INDEX</h1>
          <ul class="unordered">
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Coffee <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Tea <button>delete</button></li>
             <li>Milk <button>delete</button></li>
         </ul>
</body>
</html>
```